# What's the best way to write a big file to S3?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, pyspark, parquet, apache-zeppelin

I'm using zeppelin and spark, and I'd like to take a 2TB file from S3 and run transformations on it in Spark, and then send it up to S3 so that I can work with the file in Jupyter notebook. The transformations are pretty straightforward.

I'm reading the file as a parquet file. I think it's about 2TB, but I'm not sure how to verify.

It's about 10M row and 5 columns, so it's pretty big.

I tried to do `my_table.write.parquet(s3path)` and I tried `my_table.write.option("maxRecordsPerFile", 200000).parquet(s3path)`. How do I come up with the right way to write a big parquet file?

Comment: 10 million rows isn't necessarily big but my calculations suggest each column must have some large json blob or something? Can you give some more details on the data structure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These are the points you could consider...

#### 1) maxRecordsPerFile setting:

With

`my_table.write.parquet(s3path)`

Spark writes a single file out per task.

*The number of saved files is =  the number of partitions of the RDD/Dataframe being saved. Thus, this could result in ridiculously large files (of couse you can repartition your data and save **repartition means shuffles the data across the networks**.).*

To limit number of records per file

```
my_table.write.option("maxRecordsPerFile", numberOfRecordsPerFile..yourwish).parquet(s3path)
```

It can avoid generating huge files.

#### 2) If you are using AWS Emr (Emrfs) this could be one of the point you can consider.

[emr-spark-s3-optimized-committer](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ReleaseGuide/emr-spark-s3-optimized-committer.html)

***When the EMRFS S3-optimized Committer is Not Used :***

- When using the S3A file system.
- When using an output format other than Parquet, such as ORC or text.

#### 3) Using compression techniques , algo version and other spark configurations:

```
.config("spark.hadoop.mapreduce.fileoutputcommitter.algorithm.version", 2)
.config("spark.hadoop.mapreduce.fileoutputcommitter.cleanup-failures.ignored", true)
.config("spark.hadoop.parquet.enable.summary-metadata", false)
.config("spark.sql.parquet.mergeSchema", false)
.config("spark.sql.parquet.filterPushdown", true) // for reading purpose 
.config("mapreduce.fileoutputcommitter.algorithm.version", "2")
.config("spark.sql.parquet.compression.codec", "snappy")
.getOrCreate()
```

#### 4) fast upload and other props in case you are using s3a:

```
  .config("spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.fast.upload","true")
  .config("spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.fast.upload","true")
  .config("spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.connection.timeout","100000")
  .config("spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.attempts.maximum","10")
  .config("spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.fast.upload","true")
  .config("spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.fast.upload.buffer","bytebuffer")
  .config("spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.fast.upload.active.blocks","4")
  .config("fs.s3a.connection.ssl.enabled", "true")
```

Comment: How should I select the number of records per file?

Comment: maxRecordsPerFile ... you already writing this in your question right ?

Comment: How do I choose the number to use? I'm just guessing

Comment: It could be like Numrecordsperfile = 10 million /  (num executors * cores *  2 ) is sample I can give

Comment: Or if you don't know 10million or 20 million data then do count approx and and substitute in 10 million  with that

Comment: I tried it with 1 million and received this error: `SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Total size of serialized results of 738 tasks (1027.4 MB) is bigger than spark.driver.maxResultSize (1024.0 MB)`

Comment: This is seperate issue https://stackoverflow.com/a/47999105/647053

Answer (score 0):

1. The S3a connector will incrementally write blocks, but the (obsolete) version shipping with spark in hadoop-2.7.x doesn't handle it very well. IF you can, update *all hadoop-* Jars to 2.8.5 or 2.9.x.
2. the option `"fs.s3a.multipart.size` controls the size of the block. There's a limit of 10K blocks, so the max file you can upload is that size * 10,000. For very large files, use a bigger number than the default of "64M"