# Total size of serialised results of tasks is bigger than spark.driver.maxResultSize when running MERGE INTO on an Iceberg table

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-iceberg

I am new to both Spark and Iceberg, so I apologise in advance if the answer is obvious. I am doing a `MERGE INTO` operation on an Iceberg table using an AWS glue job (there are up to 50 worker nodes each with 32GB RAM). I am getting an error stating that the results exceeds 8GB, which is the size I have currently set for `spark.driver.maxResultSize`.

I am confused about why `spark.driver.maxResultSize` should even be involved here because I am not trying to retrieve any result. Furthermore, don't the executor nodes and the driver node of the cluster store intermediate results in disk and only load them into memory when necessary? I don't see why the driver node would try to process more data than it can handle.

Does anyone know why this is happening and if there is a way to resolve it without increasing `spark.driver.maxResultSize` any further?

Comment: Does [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74906292/15405732) answer your question?

Comment: I used coalesce to reduce the number of partitions and that seemed to solve the issue.